# Issue with creating for loop in a scatter graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Below is my code for a scatter graph. The issue i am having is that the legend displays:

a blue dot with a M next to it and then underneath it displays an orange dot with an i next to it. That is not what i wanted. I wanted it to display a blue dot with Microcar 0, then underneath it to display an orange dot with Microcar 1 next to it.

There must be something wrong with the:

```
plt.legend('Microcar'+ stri(i))
```

part of my code, but I don't know what?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

horizontal_expected =[28.96, 165.03]
vertical_expected = [196.14,-3.34]

for i in list(range(len(vertical_expected))):
    y = vertical_expected[i]
    x = horizontal_expected[i]
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.legend('Microcar' + str(i))


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case,When you are passing a string('Microcar') as an argument to plt.legend() method what happens is the first character 'M' becomes the first legend, and second character 'i' becomes the second  legend.

**Resolution**

You should pass the legends as a list of strings. Like in the below example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

horizontal_expected =[28.96, 165.03]
vertical_expected = [196.14,-3.34]
legends=[]
for i in list(range(len(vertical_expected))):
    y = vertical_expected[i]
    x = horizontal_expected[i]
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    legends.append(['Microcar' + str(i)])    

plt.legend(legends)
plt.show()
```

This would give your expected result

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 3):

There are two errors in your method:

1. Each time `plt.legend('Microcar'+ stri(i))` line is run it *overwrites* the legend.
2. The `plt.legend` method expects a `labels` argument, which is an iterable, and assigns each member of `labels`, in turn, to the components of the graph. Because a string is an iterable it assigns each *character* of the string to each graph component.

The accepted solution works, but a more readable way to do this is to label as you go.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

horizontal_expected =[28.96, 165.03]
vertical_expected = [196.14,-3.34]

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(horizontal_expected, vertical_expected)):
    plt.scatter(x, y, label='Microcar ' + str(i))

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```